# Webpack suddenly doesn't compile and has errors internally

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Webpack suddenly stopped working due to internal errors

[This is the stdout](https://pastebin.com/zVf3tTwe). (It was too long for stackoverflow)

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
 
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
 @ ./node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js 95:30-50 98:9-29
 @ ./src/defenition.js 1:0-35
 @ ./src/index.js 15:0-55 52:56-82
 
80 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
 
webpack 5.47.1 compiled with 80 errors and 10 warnings in 108881 ms
```

It also took 1 minute and 48 seconds to run.
How do I fix this?

edit: I got it fixed. The problem was `import { container } from "webpack"` in defenition.js

Comment: Can you post line 15 and surrounding lines of index.js? And defenition.js?

Comment: Maybe just try `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. the problem was `import { container } from "webpack"` in defenition.js